# Is Advaitha the only school of thought that gives highest possible status to a Jiva?

Tags: philosophy, human

There are many schools of thoughts in [Hindu philosophy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hindu_philosophy).

The most powerful or highest status is becoming a Brahman. Advaitha is the only school I know assuring that highest possible status to Jiva as the *ultimate and final* position.

Are there any other schools that assure such status to Jiva?

Comment: Advaita does NOT assert that Jiva is the the ultimate or highest. It very plainly states that it is Brahman. Your question is misleading.

Comment: No Hindu schools assert this.

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda I request you to please read again, I am not saying **Jiva as the ultimate and final position** it is **highest possible status to Jiva as the ultimate and final position**